# Vectorization identity: Weyl matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, weyl-group, vectorization

Take a ring $Z_n = \{0,1,...,n-1\}$. All operations occur modulo $n$. Consider the $n^{th}$ roots of unity $\omega_n = \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)$. Now define

$$X = \sum_a \vert{a+1}\rangle\langle{a}\vert$$
$$Z = \sum_a \omega_a \vert{a}\rangle\langle{a}\vert,$$

where $\vert a\rangle$ is a column vector of an orthonormal basis and $\langle a\vert$ is the corresponding basis row vector.

These matrices follow the commutation $XZ = \omega ZX$. The Weyl matrices are defined as $W_{a,b} = X^aZ^b$.

Vectorization of a matrix $A=\sum A_{i,j}\vert i \rangle\langle j\vert$ is defined by vec$(A) = \sum A_{i,j}\vert i \rangle\vert j\rangle$

I am given an identity vec$(\mathbb{I})$vec$(\mathbb{I})^* = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{c,d}\overline{W_{c,d}}\otimes W_{c,d}$. Could someone point out how I could prove this?

Comment: How are the bras and kets defined?

Comment: @md2perpe Sorry, will add it to the question. The bras and kets are row and column vectors respectively. Hence $\vert a\rangle\langle a \vert$ would be a projector matrix, for instance.

Comment: Is the basis arbitrary or should it be orthonormal?

Comment: @md2perpe, I believe it is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Could also be that $\{ \vert a \rangle \}$ is any basis and that $\{ \langle a \vert \}$ is the dual basis such that $\langle a' \vert a'' \rangle = \delta(a', a''),$ i.e. $=1$ if $a'=a'',$ and $=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Does that help with the proof? I tried a few things where I expanded it out and it went nowhere

Comment: At least one needs to know enough what things are to be able to use them. Now I don't understand what is $X^a$ and $Z^b$. Is it $X$ to the power of $a$ and $Z$ to the power of $b$?

Comment: Yes, that's right - it's raising to the powers